# why is my middle div out of place?

Tags: css

I have a header, middle,footer and a right side, but the middle div wont line up next to the right div. I don't know why this is happening. Can someone explain to me why this is happening?

This is my jfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4qdyK/3/

As you can see, my middle div and header div aren't even different in size.

**Middle:**

```
.middle{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    font-family:serif;
    border-style:dotted none;
    border-width:1px; 
    border-color:black;
    font-size:14px;
    font-style:italic;
    width:60%;
    margin-left:15%;
    padding:0px;
    height: 1%; overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 720px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow:hidden;
    height: auto !important;  
}
```

**Header:**

```
.header{
    font-family:serif;
    width:60%; 
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    margin-left:15%;
    height: 150px;
    text-align:right;
    border-radius: 12px;
}
```

The margin is the same. Yet the header is out of place.

Might be a very stupid mistake yet I honestly can't see it.

Comment: You would need to float the middle div to the left.

Comment: @Paulie_D I put float:left; on the middle and footer. I changed the width of the middle and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Loko remove `overflow:hidden;` from `.middle`

Comment: @Vucko that didn't work?

Comment: @Loko you have two `overflow:hidden;` in your `.middle` - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4qdyK/21/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.middle{
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
font-family:serif;
border-style:dotted none;
border-width:1px; 
border-color:black;
font-size:14px;
font-style:italic;
width:60%;
margin-left:15%;
padding:0px;
min-height: 720px;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

If i understood right the above code is working